# sublime text 2 : search for specific phrases, variables, constants

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to search within all of a specific project's files for a specific CONSTANT.  I like the fuzzy match abilities of goto anything, but I don't think you can seach in this way for specific phrases. I have also read through http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/21604-search-replace-across-projectsdirectories/, although most of the comments are close to a year old. Can someone advise me on the best way to do a search and replace now within all files of a project?

Thanks in advance.

Bill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Believe find and replace across projects has been implemented. Bring up the "Find in Files" prompt (`ctrl+shift+f` in linux and windows or `super+shift+f` in OS X). By leaving the `Where` field empty, it should search through all project folders, as well as open files that aren't in a project. You can use regex replace, case sensitive, etc as you would with a normal find and replace within a single file.

Hope that helps.